# Eigen 3.2.1 + MKL = C4244 Compiler warning

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl

Anyone experiencing these warnings when compiling projects with Eigen and EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL flag defined? I'm following the instructions here:  http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html. This only happens when I `#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>`

Example of compile log:

eigen3.2.1\eigen\src/Eigenvalues/RealSchur_MKL.h(76): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
eigen3.2.1\eigen\src/Eigenvalues/ComplexSchur_MKL.h(87): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
eigen3.2.1\eigen\src/Eigenvalues/SelfAdjointEigenSolver_MKL.h(80): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data

I know what these warnings mean, but to resolve them I would need to change the library code. Short of suppressing these warnings, do you have any suggestions (just in case somehow I have missed something)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 64 bit platforms Eigen uses 64 bit integers to encode the dimensions of its matrices. The MKL wrapper uses 32 integers, which might overflow if your matrix size exceeds 2 billion rows or columns.

Comment: Does this mean I need to compile to ILP64 (64-bit integers)? But in the link provided, Eigen setup suggests that on a 64-bit system, you should use only LP64 (32-bit integers)...?

Comment: You should use the LP64 interface as recommended in the Eigen documentation (despite the compilation warnings). The ILP64 library is not supported at this point.